# Facebook send message through iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I am using this code to send a message:

```
//send message
     NSString *friendList = @"1372394537";
     NSMutableDictionary* params =
     [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      @"Check this out.",  @"message",
      friendList, @"suggestions",
      nil];

     [self.facebook dialog:@"apprequests"
                 andParams:params
               andDelegate:self];
     //send message
```

My app logs in with facebook, shows a friend list, and then adds the Friend's ID's in the friendList, but they receive no message!! Why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> #### What you are sending is a request and not a message. There is a big difference.
>
> The message you are talking about is simply a parameter that you can pass along with the request.

The most frequent problem that I see people dealing with when requests do not arrive is that the application is set to sandbox mode. If the application is in sandbox mode, only users listed in the "roles" section within your application will be able to receive the requests (admins, developers, testers...).

One other thing that could be at work here is that the canvas URL is not set for your application. When users act on requests they are sent to the application's canvas URL. When you don't set that value there is no place for the request to send the user so the request is nullified and doesn't reach the user.

So two things for you to try -

1. Remove your application from sandbox mode.
2. Make sure that you have set the canvas URL property for your application.

Comment: When you mean "canvas URL" are you talking about the app id they give you on Facebook, the one you add to the info plist?

Comment: No. The `app_id` is a different parameter. I'm talking about the setting in your application at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/. It's in the "basic" tab. These are settings *within Facebook*.

Comment: Now I set the sandbox to no and still doesn't work, so I think it's problem 2

Comment: Well if sandbox mode was turned on it could have been both :)

Comment: I found it: URL scheme suffix. But what do I have to write in there?

Comment: actually the sandbox was off

Comment: Ok, and now in the canvas URL what do I need to write??

Comment: Essentially you can write what ever you want... Users will arrive at your canvas after they accept the request.

Comment: The point is that I didn't understand what a canvas has to do with all of this. How do I set it up? Do I need to add a code in my ios app? Sorry, but I son't understand...

Comment: Users have to be redirected somewhere after they accept an invite. Your canvas url can simply reopen your app or redirect users to wherever you want.

Comment: Is it this url I need to change: NSString *const FBSessionStateChangedNotification =
@"com.facebook.samples.SendRequestsHowTo:FBSessionStateChangedNotification";

Comment: The point is that when I initiate the request, a pop up appears in my app, and when I press send the pop up disappears

Comment: I don't have any experience in developing for iOS so I don't really know what all that means. All I can tell you is that if you want to use requests, you have to set the canvas URL. The canvas URL is basically where normal apps on Facebook sit. In your case, on a mobile device, you'll just have to send your users back to the application when they reach the canvas URL.

Comment: Ok, and what is the url to send back to the app?

Comment: I have no idea :) Like I said, I don't have any experience developing for Apple devices... You can try [this](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html).. It's just the first google search result I got...

Comment: The main question is - do the requests work after you have set the canvas URL?

Comment: they do work now, but when I press on a review on fb, I am directed to an inexistant facebook page, not to my app!! or to the app store

Comment: What do you mean by "review"?

Comment: Ah... yes... after a user clicks on your request they will be redirected to the canvas URL that you defined - from there you can (i beleive) open your application on the phone...

Comment: I will search on the internet what url I have to enter in order to open the app on the iPhone!! Thanks